# How to get the value of one specific JSON key

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I've searched for the answer to this question, in many places. However, the only thing I can find is how to get the values of all of a certain key in a JSON file. I would like to know if there is a way to get the value of one specific key. I have a JSON file set up like so:

```
{
"Category": [{
    "Subcategory": {
        "Item1": {
            "key1": "value1",
            "key2": "value2",
            "key3": "value3",
            "key4": "value4",
            "key5": "value5",
            "key6": "value6"
        },
        "Item2": {
            "key1": "value1",
            "key2": "value2",
            "key3": "value3",
            "key4": "value4",
            "key5": "value5",
            "key6": "value6"
            }
        }    
    }]
}
```

I would like to know a method using JQuery/Javascript to get, for example, the value of Key1 in Item1(value1).

Comment: `Category[0].Subcategory.Item1.key1`

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Would this work in the context of a script in a separate file using console.log(Category[0].Subcategory.Item1.key1?

Comment: Example: `var body = JSON.parse(file_contents); val = body.Category[0].Subcategory.Item1.key1;`

Comment: Load the JSON, `JSON.parse` the text content to an object, then read the properties you want.

Comment: @Zuve, a variable in the global scope is accessible to all scripts that were loaded after it's declaration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like other comments and answers, you can easily get the value for a specific hard-coded key like this:

```
Category[0].Subcategory.Item1.key1
```

But if you have dynamic keys, you can do like this:

```
var categories = {
    "Category": [{
        "Subcategory": {
            "Item1": {
                "key1": "value1",
                "key2": "value2",
                "key3": "value3",
                "key4": "value4",
                "key5": "value5",
                "key6": "value6"
            },
            "Item2": {
                "key1": "value1",
                "key2": "value2",
                "key3": "value3",
                "key4": "value4",
                "key5": "value5",
                "key6": "value6"
            }
        }
    }]
};

var itemKeyName = "Item1";
var keyName = "key1";

console.log(categories.category[0].Subcategory[itemKeyName][keyName];
```

Comment: How would I use the console.log from another file. Would it be something like console.log('path/filename.json'.category[0].SubCategory.Item1.Key1);

Comment: "How would I use the console.log from another file" - does not work that way. In javascript, you cannot require another file. Although you can load it over XHR request, parse it and then log the contents to the console.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do:

```
Category[0].Subcategory.Item1.key1
```